# KONG API Gateway - Why route are not Unique?

Tags: kong

I'm using [KONG Community Edition (0.13.x)](https://docs.konghq.com/0.13.x/).
 While I trying to create/add [`routes`](https://docs.konghq.com/0.13.x/admin-api/#add-route), It's creating `route instance` again and again even if I using **same data**.

**Example**
end-point - `/routes/`
post payload

```
{
    "protocols": [
        "http",
        "https"
    ],
    "methods": null,
    "paths": [
        "/foo/bar",
        "/foo/foobar/bar"
    ],
    "service": {
        "id": "b23e0443-1040-4839-9c92-5e0c0e2abe3f"
    }
}
```

Why this happening? May be it's a feature, but I couldn't understand what is the feature in it :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all, POST requests to an API (such as creating a route in the Kong Admin API) are not idempotent (at least if the API follows REST principles). This means it DOES matter how often you send it and if you send it twice it will trigger two operations.

Kong tolerates two or more routes with the same paths, however the proxy reference specifies the behaviour and the matching priorities: https://docs.konghq.com/2.0.x/proxy/#matching-priorities

In your case, the last rule applies: first one wins.

EDIT: I just noticed that your question was posted more than 2 years ago. However, it might help others with the same question :-)